# Can a continuous linear form have a norm of infinity?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

We know that a linear form $A \in V^{*}$ is continuous iff $$ \exists C: C\in R, ||Av|| \leq c ||v|| \forall v \in V $$ 
but we know too that $$ ||A|| = min\{c>0:||Av|| \leq C||v|| \forall v\in V\}$$
Does that mean that the norm of **any** continuous linear form is bounded since the set above must contain at least a real number?
Sorry if the question seems trivial I'm just new to functional analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is exactly like that. For linear operators between normed spaces, continuity and boundedness are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, a final question, does it differ if the dimension of any of those normed spaces is not finite.

Comment: No. In fact, in finite dimension the question is moot because every linear map is bounded. In infinite dimension non-continuous maps exist, and boundedness is the right point of view to address continuity.